# Is it possible to unit test IIS rewrite rules?

Tags: unit-testing, iis

There is a user interface to help create and test individual rewrite rules for IIS. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Is there a way to create automated test for rewrite rules? 
Generally, i.e. server agnostic, or specifically for IIS.

Comment: It is possible to create such unit testing but you are fully on your own developing it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns